# How do I hide specifically "private_key" from being viewed by everyone as every thing is getting stored on the array including private_key

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

How do I hide specifically "private_key" from being viewed by everyone as every thing is getting stored on the array including private_key?

I want to display all the data like address,user Id,first name,last name to be viewed by everyone on the blockchain except for the private_key.

```
struct User {
    address wallet_address;  
    string userId;
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    string email_id;
    bool set;
    string private_key;
}

mapping(address => User) users; 
mapping(string => address) walletAccount;
mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
User[] public registeredArray;

function createNewUser(
    address userAcc,
    string memory _id,
    string memory firstName,
    string memory lastName,
    string memory emailId,
    string memory _private_key
) public {
    User storage user = users[userAcc];
    users[userAcc] = User(
        userAcc,
        _id,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        emailId,
        true,
        _private_key
    ); 
    walletAccount[emailId] = userAcc;
    registeredArray.push(users[userAcc]);
}

function getAllUsers() public view returns (User[] memory) {
    return registeredArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to keep it private to the package?  A more specific implementation of your solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's on a private chain, anything you ever store or transact on the Ethereum network, becomes public. So there's no way to make the value not readable.

E.g. even if the `users` mapping doesn't have any visibility modifier, so it's `internal` by default, its values are still publicly readable by querying the corresponding [storage slots](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#getstorageat).

You'll need to change your approach to not store the private key. For example let the user sign a message off-chain, and store the already signed message.